Virtualization in VirtualBox and CPU command sets
I'm slightly confused about following: Oracle VirtualBox - is it only capable of running virtual machines that are in the same command set as the host's physical CPU? I know so little of virtualization that I never thought about this until I hit it yesterday: a friend has a Macbook with M1 CPU (ARM, yes?) and an .ova file he's downloaded and wanted to spin up on his VirtualBox (on the said Macbook). When we "import appliance", it shows Windows 7 x86 icon on that VM and attempting to run it gives us an vbox_e_platform_arch_not_supported exception.
"What do we press" to make it work - does he need a different physical machine to host this VM?

Yes, M1 is ARM architecture. Is it a requirement to run the original Windows 7 x86 VM ? I don't think there is an easy work-around for that. The architectures are not compatible. Although I haven't tried it, an alternative would be to use virtualisation software that supports ARM (like Parallels Desktop For Mac ), and then run ARM-compatible operating system such as Windows 11 for ARM.

For me, it looks like this question would be much better suited for Superuser.com than Softwareengineering, but I think we need to ask a mod for that, since it already got an upvoted answer here.

“Is it only capable of running virtual machines that are in the same command set as the host's physical CPU?” - Yes; There is absolutely no way to run a x86 VM on a system with an ARM processor.

To the best of my knowledge - and I would love to be proved wrong, as I have the same problem - VirtualBox will not run on ARM architecture (of which Apple's M1 is a type). VirtualBox functions as a type-2 hypervisor and runs VMs natively on x86 systems. It does not emulate other architectures. Since it does not emulate x86 on ARM, it cannot run an x86 Windows VM on an M1 or M2 Mac. This limitation means that VirtualBox cannot run a VM that relies on a different CPU instruction set than the host machine, and there is currently no ARM support available.
The only real work-around that I'm aware of is first to use ARM-based virtualisation software (VirtualBox is an x86 VM), and then run an ARM-based version of the target OS - for example Windows 11 for ARM. The OS that your friend has - Windows 7 - does not have an ARM version.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-arm-based-pcs-faq-477f51df-2e3b-f68f-31b0-06f5e4f8ebb5
One popular virtualisation software that does run on ARM-based hardware is Parallels Desktop 20 For Mac, which as the name suggests is designed for Mac hardware:
https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/
Another option is "UTM | Virtual machines for Mac" which has one benefit over Parallels, namely that it is free and open source. On the downside, as far as I know Microsoft does not (officially) support it's ARM-based operating systems on UTM, whereas Microsoft does support Parallels.
https://mac.getutm.app/

"What do we press" to make it work - does he need a different physical machine to host this VM?

Of course another solution is to run VirtualBox on different machine entirely - an x86 machine, in which case you should be able to use the .ova file for Windows 7.
As an aside I wonder what the reason for wanting a VM are ? If it's just to isolate environments, then you and your friend should consider containers instead - such as docker:
https://www.docker.com/

The whole operation is for the sake of accessing the contents supplied as a complete VM - more details I do not have, but unfortunately it is that particular machine that we need to spin up, either on that Mac (preferably, but as far as I see now, that is not likely to happen) or somewhere else.

OK, then in that case I think your only option is to use a compatible (ie x86) machine.

You can get a used Intel Mac mini on eBay for very little money. Silicon macs have a compiler built in that will translate Intel Mac applications to ARM  Mac applications and I think parallels may be using that to run Intel-based VMs.

VirtualBox absolutely runs on MacOS. Windows on ARM absolutely will run within a VirtualBox VM. Of course this limitation to run OS that supports ARM isn’t limited to VirtualBox all hypervisors running on any ARM processor would only support ARM guest operating systems. The claim VirtualBox does not support ARM is factual incorrect.

Docker running on a system with an ARM processor can’t run Windows 7
